# how do i fix Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined in reactjs single page application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, single-page-application

I was trying to check the role and if the role is for admin then display the role admin otherwise display member. It shows an error that cannot read property may I know what was my error and how to fix such error. here is my code:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
    import "./App.css";

    import AuthService from "./services/auth.service";

    import Login from "./components/login.component";
    import Register from "./components/register.component";
    import Home from "./components/home.component";
    import Profile from "./components/profile.component";
    import BoardUser from "./components/board-user.component";
    import BoardModerator from "./components/board-moderator.component";
    import BoardAdmin from "./components/board-admin.component";

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.logOut = this.logOut.bind(this);

        this.state = {
          showModeratorBoard: false,
          showAdminBoard: false,
          currentUser: undefined
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const user = AuthService.getCurrentUser();
        if (user) {
          this.setState({
            currentUser: AuthService.getCurrentUser(),
             showModeratorBoard: user.roles.includes("admin"),
             showAdminBoard: user.roles.includes("member")

          });
        }
      }

      logOut() {
        AuthService.logout();
      }

      render() {
        const { currentUser, showModeratorBoard, showAdminBoard } = this.state;

        return (
          <Router>
            <div>
              <nav className="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
                <Link to={"/"} className="navbar-brand">
                  bezKoder
                </Link>
                <div className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li className="nav-item">
                    <Link to={"/home"} className="nav-link">
                      Home
                    </Link>
                  </li>

                   {showModeratorBoard && (
                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <Link to={"/mod"} className="nav-link">
                        Moderator Board
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  )}

                  {showAdminBoard && (
                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <Link to={"/admin"} className="nav-link">
                        Admin Board
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  )} 

                  {currentUser && (
                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <Link to={"/user"} className="nav-link">
                        User
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  )}
                </div>

                {currentUser ? (
                  <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <Link to={"/profile"} className="nav-link">
                        {currentUser.username}
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <a href="/login" className="nav-link" onClick={this.logOut}>
                        LogOut
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  </div>
                ) : (
                  <div className="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <Link to={"/login"} className="nav-link">
                        Login
                      </Link>
                    </li>

                    <li className="nav-item">
                      <Link to={"/register"} className="nav-link">
                        Sign Up
                      </Link>
                    </li>
                  </div>
                )}
              </nav>

              <div className="container mt-3">
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path={["/", "/home"]} component={Home} />
                  <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                  <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
                  <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                  <Route path="/user" component={BoardUser} />
                  <Route path="/mod" component={BoardModerator} />
                  <Route path="/admin" component={BoardAdmin} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Router>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

It shows error shown is 
**Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined**

```
if (user) {
  31 |   this.setState({
  32 |     currentUser: AuthService.getCurrentUser(),
> 33 |      showModeratorBoard: user.roles.includes("admin"),
     | ^  34 |      showAdminBoard: user.roles.includes("member")
  35 |      
  36 |   });
```

Thank you!!

Comment: What is the return value of the `AuthService.getCurrentUser()` method?

Comment: @MartinHorváth the return value is return `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) to get `roles` property value from `user` object and then set the default value for `roles` as an empty string, so that if `roles` is undefined then roles value will set to the default value of `''` like:

```
if (user) {
  const { roles = '' } = user;
  this.setState({
    currentUser: AuthService.getCurrentUser(),
    showModeratorBoard: roles.includes("admin"),
    showAdminBoard: roles.includes("member")    
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @palash it was showing the error because the role was undefined. may I know how to pass the role so that I can show link for the admin if logged in user is AdminBoard and show ModeratBroard link if the sign user is "member" and show only user if signIn user is "user" only. I'm using get/post role from backend through jwt token.

Comment: You want to pass the role to what?

Comment: @palasH  I want to pass role to `user` so that I can check if the role of user is admin or mod or only user.

Comment: Oh ok, but this seems like a different question. Could you please create a new post for this and mark this answer as [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/205255), if the issue mentioned in this post related to "_Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined_" has been resolved.

Comment: @palasH I have created a new post and here is the link  https://stackoverflow.com/q/61252129/12856366?stw=2 for the question. could you please help me with that issue.